How to choose between ROS 2 Humble and Jazzy?
I am a beginner working with a team to develop ROS 2-related applications, but I am unsure about which ROS 2 version to choose. Many people recommend Humble or Jazzy, and it seems that Humble is more stable while Jazzy has newer features.
What major features does Jazzy have compared to Humble? Would choosing Jazzy offer more advantages for my future development? I have reviewed the official release notes but couldn't find any significant advantages.

Do you use Ubuntu 22.04 or Ubuntu 24.04?

Either way, I can choose it according to the ros2 version.


Some new core features of jazzy (and iron) are summarized here.
Differences on package level very much depends on your application and which packages you use.
Humble will be supported until May 2027, and Jazzy until May 2029.
Humble is more stable up to now, but I guess that Jazzy will become as stable after the upcoming ROSCon in October.
New features very likely won't be backported to humble any more by the package maintainers.

